# SSIS - varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, varcharmax

I have sp which concatenate a long string and which passes back to SSIS. but currently SSIS is only picking the string partially.

Is there a method which allows the a T-SQL stored procedure to pass a long string to SSIS ? Currently the parameter is defined as `VARCHAR(max)`

I tried using a SSIS Object variable and it does not allow me to convert it back to string. How do I convert a SSIS Object to string

```
Convert.ToString(Dts.Variable["ObjVar"]Value) ;
```

I am using SSIS 2012.

Thanks

Comment: SSIS for 2012+ or pre 2012?

Comment: According to this, there is no limit on variable size, but there is a limit on expression length.   What are you doing with this string that makes you think it is only partially loaded?    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e056562d-9116-40c1-86bd-60e53166e727/maximum-size-of-the-ssis-string-variable

Answer (score 1):

The limitation appears to me being in the datatype used on the SQL Server side.
To overcome it use `TEXT` - Variable length storage with maximum size of 2GB data (or `NTEXT` if you expect Unicode, and then it is limited to 1GB)